# what is the xpath of this element

Tags: xml, xpath, scrapy

I am scraping a page

I want to extract this data

I got the xpath for it from google chrome which is

```
//*[@id="oldID"]/li[N]/em[J]
```

and I tried to get the result. but it gives me the result of another element in the page. which is ![enter image description here][2]
and which its xpath is:

```
//*[newID"]/li[N+1]/em[J]
```

why please?

Comment: When you say "tried to get the result", what tool are you using? Perhaps the page is changing within the browser after it is loaded, so the structure in Chrome is not the same as the raw source you are scraping.

Comment: It's a scripted page. The element you're looking for may not exist until after the script has run. (I haven't attempted to read the scripts or to look at the raw document as fetched.)

Comment: @IMSoP I am using scrapy with python. I already make the tag of scrapy. How could the page be changed in the browser after loading ?is that possible? if yes please give me a description of this situation, i haven't head about it

Comment: @keshlam your assumption is not possible because I already can scrap the item about the "Dealer" item

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Simple: JavaScript. It's technically known as "Dynamic HTML", although that phrase is rarely used these days. If you look at a site like Facebook, you will see that almost none of the content is actually included in the initial source, it all being fetched and rendered dynamically.

Comment: @IMSoP but this is not the case here. because I already can scraped the other items.

Comment: @IMSoP I checked the chrome developers options. there is no java script requests

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli It doesn't need to be the element you are looking for which has changed, just the structure of the page such that the XPath expression no longer points at the same place.

Comment: It doesn't have to be AJAX either, that was just an example. There's plenty of JS loaded on that page; if some of it is adding or removing elements, it will affect an XPath expression like the one you have which is relying on there being exactly 8 `li`s in a particular `ul`.

Comment: @IMSoP so what is the solution ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli To use a more targeted XPath expression, or to determine the XPath by hand from the actual XML you're processing, rather than relying on Chrome's rendering of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML snippet from the page

```
                            <li>
            <span>Dealer</span><em>Some dealer</em><br />
            <span>Location </span><em>some location</em><br>                <span>City </span><em>Some City</em><br>                <span>Country </span><em>Some Country</em><br>                <span>Telephone </span><em>0123456789</em><br>                <span>Mobile </span><em>1234567890</em><br>                <span>Website </span><em><a href="http://www.example.com" >http://www.example.com</a></em><br>               
            <br />
            <a href="detail.php?id=123456">View all products</a>
            </li>
```

If you want to select the Dealer name I suggest you find the `span` with "Dealer" string in it and then fetch the `em` just after it:

```
//span[normalize-space(.) = "Dealer"]/following-sibling::em[1]/text()
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I got an empty result because "as I think" the spider tries to go the the other `ul` elements which doesn't have the `dealer` span

Comment: could you tell me the reason why is that happening please? i want to understand

Comment: I'm not sure, but Chrome's parser is probably way smarter than lxml's (used in Scrapy), so Chrome may add some elements to fix incorrect markup. It's generally dangerous to select based on `[N]` (if it's not position `1` or `last()`) and safer to select based on neighbouring clues, here a text label before your target text